# unable to execute /usr/local/bin/pip3: Permission denied

Tags: installation, pip, upgrade

I am trying to:

**pip3 install --upgrade pip3**

*sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/pip3: Permission denied*

why permission is dennied?

similar error when i try too install package for example:

**sudo pip3 install medaka**

*sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/pip3: Permission denied*

Comment: does `/usr/local/bin/pip3` have the executable bit set?

Comment: how do i check about it, not sure what do you mean?

Comment: Can you add the ouput of `ls -la  /usr/local/bin/pip3`?

Comment: Thanks for the help and inputs , meanwhile did a fresh install of the the entire system, now everything works, but will keep your suggestion in mind if it happens again ))